# Need a Global Optimisation Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm, fminsearch

I am working on a Global Optimization problem, whose algorithm is shown in figure (1). My objective is to find two values (Gamma12 and epsilon1) for a given value of epsilon2.

I know that the upper and lower bounds of values Gamma12 and epsilon1 will be anywhere between 0.1 and -0.1.

Can anybody suggest a global optimization algorithm, i.e. the algorithm which can be able to find out the values of Gamma12 and epsilon1 at the global minimum error possible.

I tried, fminsearch, fmincon, patternsearch algorithms in matlab, the problem with those algorithms is the initial guess. I was unable to find the initial guess.

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: The phrase "initial guess" means what it says.  You can pick any value and start improving from there.  `(0, 0)` is just fine.

Comment: I tried `(0, 0)` but is is not working, the value of error is very high i want the error to be in the order of `10^-5`, but I am getting `67.89` I think the program is giving local minimum. I want to find the values corresponding to global minimum @btilly

Comment: I'm not flagging this because I don't know the answer to the following question, but: is this more of a math question, or is this within the scope of questions allowed on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @VijayKumar Yes, hill climbing can get stuck in local minimums.  Try from several random locations.  Try a smaller step size.  If you know what the answer is supposed to be, try with the known answer and see if you've set it up properly.

Comment: If there truly was an optimization algorithm **guaranteed** to give you the global minimum then it would be the only algorithm ever used (and the inventor would be very rich) - in general it doesn't exist.  In this instance you most likely want to take a look at the [MultiStart](https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/multistart.html) function, which will start your code at various different `x0` and return the one that gives the lowest cost.  However, there is no guarantee that this will not be a local minimum.

Comment: genetic algorithm could be a good option but as Phil said its not guaranteed,

Comment: @PhilGoddard I have an optimization algorithm guaranteed to find the global minimum, but unfortunately not in finite time.

Comment: @PhilGoddard , Thank you very much. At present I am using fmincon() coupled with several initial start points, hopefully the program is giving a global optima instead of stopping at a local optima.